# How do code "this" type of "drop" details?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find out how to write this function but I'm not sure what it is called and where I can find one for an example. I'm a beginner so I'm only familiar with HTML and CSS.

It's NOT a dropdown bar. It's a text that you could click and when you click it, it immediately shows another body of text right underneath it. It does not involve loading anything, as if it is already there. It is immediate. I want to have something in my website where if I have a name of something, there is an arrow by it that says "details" and when you click it, it shows a whole body of text with details. This button typically seems to have a small arrow next to it. Again, it is not any type of menus or bars, it shows a whole body of texts or images.

Comment: Have you seen jquery toggle? what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't mean to ask for it to be done or anything. I just don't know where I can find references online that pertains to it. I'm not even sure what it would be called. If someone could point me to the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to show a hidden element. This is a very basic example, look into jQuery `show()` & `hide()`. You're essentially setting the `display:none` CSS rule on the hidden text to something like `display:block'.

```js
$('#foo').on('click', function(){
  $('#text').show();
});
```

```css
#text {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="foo">Details</a>
<div id="text">This is a test message for the text.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very close to what I was looking for. I will study further into this area. I appreciate the inputs.

Comment: No problem - please accept the answer if you feel this is resolved.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp